vba_Selenium: Enter login crediantials into popup in browser where not able to view html code of popup
Need code, how to enter login/password into a browser popup where not able to view the html code of the popup.
I tried using the codes but not able to do as needed..
Sub test()

Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
ch.AddArgument "start-maximized" ' Maximizar la pantalla del navegador
ch.Get ("http://test:test@webpage.com/#/")

End Sub

Thank you for the support here is the webpage.
